# Should I always use await in a chain of async functions return in Javascript?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

Consider 2 ways of writing code:

The 1st ways: return instantly without **await** in async function.

```
function f4() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(2);
    }, 3000);
  }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
}

function f3() {
  return f4();
}

function f2() {
  return f3();
}

function f1() {
  return f2();
}

async function main() {
  await f1();
}

(async () => await main())();
```

and

the 2nd way: use await in every async function.

```
function f4() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(2);
    }, 3000);
  }).catch((e) => console.log(e));
}

async function f3() {
  return await f4();
}

async function f2() {
  return await f3();
}

async function f1() {
  return await f2();
}

async function main() {
  await f1();
}

(async () => await main())();
```

I think the 2nd way needs more time to execute code. But I'm not sure about that.

We see, when we use the 1st way, just only 1 Promise will go to callback. But with the 2nd way, we will have more than 1 Promise go into callback.

Which way gives better performance?
Thank you very much.

Comment: And now add `throw new Error('test')` inside `f2` and compare stacktraces in the exception when you catch it in the `main`.

Comment: @Anatoly I see the difference. But what it's importance?

Comment: It's just a sidenote to you to understand that sometimes it's important to see the more accurate stackrace and what was the source of a certain error.

Answer (score 2):

Awaiting a Promise and immediately returning it inside an `async` function [has no real benefit](https://maximorlov.com/linting-rules-for-asynchronous-code-in-javascript/#6-no-return-await).

The value will be wrapped in a Promise again because `async` functions always return a Promise. You might as well return the initial Promise returned by `f4` all the way to `main` instead of unwrapping and wrapping it along the way.

Comment: The only exception is when you need to catch exceptions inside intermediately called functions